# Multiple Values in one "SMW Page Forms" field

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

I ran into a problem with Semantic Mediawiki using the Page Forms extension.
I wanted to create a field in a Page Form, that can take more than one value. So I decided to use the *tokens* input type.

The problem is the following: If I type some values into the form field and save the page, Page Form puts all the values - seperated with commas - into one single SMW value.

For example: I have a form that will create a page about a scientific paper. And in this form I have a field that is called *Authors*. And when I fill the field with two Authors, lets say Pascal and Tesla, then the final page does not have the two SMW values `[[Author::Pascal]]` and `[[Author::Tesla]]` - It has the SMW value `[[Author::Pascal, Tesla]]`.

Does anyone know, how I can achieve the mapping from different values in the form field to different values as SMW strings?

Thanks and greets,
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Multiple values for the same field](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Page_Forms/Page_Forms_and_templates#arraymap) covers this.

Put the following in your corresponding template:

```
{{#arraymap:{{{Author|}}}|,|x|[[Author::x]]}}
```